# Does live travel tracking of user possible in django website

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am working on Django website and I want to implement user live travel tracking.Is it possible to implement live tracking of user in the Django website.If Yes, How it is possible.

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: How it is possible.Is there any tutorial for that@mhhabib